# Regex pattern with positive and negative lookahead

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like `[key1=value1, key2=value2]`. It may also contain only one key like `[key1=value1]` or many more keys. How can I write a regex to retrieve

**expected**

```
Group1: key1=value1
Group2: key2=value2
```

I've tried the pattern `/(?<=\[)(.*)=(.*)(,)*(?=\])/` [here](https://regex101.com/r/tBZiPo/1), but it gives me

**Actual**

```
Group1: key1=value1, key2
Group2: value2
```

Comment: Can `value` contain commas? Can keys contain whitespaces? Is this text one whole string, or is it part of a larger string? Do you need to make sure if the format is correct when trying to extract key-value pairs if it is a whole string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes value can contain commas and keys can contain whitespaces. The text is one whole string. Not sure what you mean by format is correct.

Comment: Try to extract them all with `(\w[^=]*)=(.*?)(?=]|,\s*\w[^=]*=)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/YedIvr/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much. This solves my problem.

Comment: Can key contain comma?

Comment: @Pshemo No keys cannot contain commas. The accepted solution works perfectly for my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may extract those pairs of keys and values using

```
(\w[^,=]*)=(.*?)(?=]|,\s*\w[^,=]*=)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YedIvr/3)

**Details**

- `(\w[^,=]*)` - Group 1: a word char followed with 0+ chars other than `=`  and `,`
- `=` - a `=` char
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars, other than line break chars, as few as possible, up to the leftmost occurrence of
- `(?=]|,\s*\w[^,=]*=)` - a `]` char or `,`, 0+ whitespaces, word char and then 0+ chars other than `=` and `,` and then a `=`.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/RFgJO8):

```
String s = "[key1=value1, key2=value2, key 3= text,value # 3]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w[^,=]*)=(.*?)(?=]|,\\s*\\w[^,=]*=)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println("Key-value pair found:");
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1).trim());
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2).trim()); 
}
```

Output:

```
Key-value pair found:
key1
value1
Key-value pair found:
key2
value2
Key-value pair found:
key 3
text,value # 3
```

Comment: Just found out that this fails for `String s = "[key1=value1, key2=value2, key 3= text,value # 3, key4=value4]";` The 3rd group has `key 3= text` and the 4th group has `value # 3, key4=value4`

Comment: @KshitijBajracharya Yes, it is too tricky to detect the start of the key name if it may contain spaces and values may contain `,`.. How can you define the key name left-hand boundary? If you can't, no regex will work.

Comment: I see you [say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54549250/regex-pattern-with-positive-and-negative-lookahead/54549490?noredirect=1#comment95899451_54549250) *No keys cannot contain commas.* So, use `(\w[^,=]*)=(.*?)(?=]|,\s*\w[^,=]*=)`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/YedIvr/3).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :)